# Attempting to understand statistics from the ground up, can someone translate this definition on random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

[image]

For context, I am an incoming MSc Economics student attempting to fill in the gaps in my statistical knowledge. I have been working through Probability, Statistics and Econometrics(Oliver Linton), however I have noticed that everything has a far more rigorous treatment than I expected. I would appreciate some clarification on what is going on here.

My understanding is that it is effectively mapping a set of elements from a sample space to a measurable probability space (Correct me if I am wrong). I would appreciate some clarification on the notation and what each of the mathematical statements is expressing.

Comment: It is difficult to be specific without knowing your background knowledge.  For example do you understand *sigma algebra*? $(S,\mathcal A, P)$ is a probability space while $X$ is a mapping (or function) from $S$ to $\mathbb R$ (or to a subset of $\mathbb R$)

Comment: More picky: what does "it" refer to in your last paragraph?  Are you referring to some particular part of the quoted passage, or they whole thrust of what the passage is about?  If the latter, maybe you should also read some other text book, which might motivate things better.

Comment: @Henry I have an elementary knowledge of sigma-algebras i.e. that they are a well-defined set within the sample space since they contain the (empty set, sample space, and all unions and complements) it is useful to use them as they don't behave irrationally. How they are used is somewhat puzzling, however.

Comment: @kimchilover I was referring to the whole thing. Are there any resources you might suggest that offers a lighter introduction to this?